# C# and xml: xs:dateTime and DateTime comparesion

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, xsd

I have an xml object 'Date' type of xs:dateTime:

```
<MyTable>
<Date>2012-06-18T:00:00:00</Date>
...[some other data]...
</MyTable>
```

I'm using DataSet to get data from my xml.

I want to select all rows from table where Date >= given date:

```
MyTable.Select("Date >" + givenDate.ToString());
```

How in this way I should convert givenDate to string? Using mask? Or it's enough to  simply use givenDate.ToString() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xs:dateTime` allows multiple format alternatives, all based on [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  If you want to include the timezone information in the format, which may be useful for lossless transfer into a different time zone, use this:

```
ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

otherwise this:

```
ToString("s");
```